# Auto mapping (with AutoMapper) from DTO to an entity with many-to-many relationship in it

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, automapper

I'm having a problem that is reflected in the following example. i've created a POST method in my BookController to create a Book entity:

here's my code:

```
public class Book
{
    public int BookId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<BookCategory> BookCategories { get; set; }
}

public class BookCategory
{
    public int BookId { get; set; }
    public virtual Book Book { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

my DTOs:

```
public class BookDto
{
    public int BookId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public ICollection<CategoryDto> Categories { get; set; }
}

public class CategoryDto
{
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
}
```

automapper configuration:

```
        CreateMap<Book, BookDto>().ReverseMap();
        CreateMap<BookCategory, CategoryDto>()
            .ForMember(d => d.CategoryId, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.CategoryId))
            .ForMember(d => d.CategoryName, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.Category.CategoryName));
        CreateMap<CategoryDto, BookCategory>().ForMember(d => d.CategoryId, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.CategoryId));

        CreateMap<BookDto, Book>().AfterMap((s, d) =>
        {
            foreach (var bookCategory in d.BookCategories)
            {
                bookCategory.BookId = s.BookId;
            }
        });
```

this is the DTO i'm trying to map to entity:

```
        BookDto model = new BookDto()
        {
            Title = "Test book",
            Categories = new List<CategoryDto>()
            {
                new CategoryDto()
                {
                    CategoryId = 1,
                    CategoryName = "drama"
                }
            },
        };
```

BookDto is a new book, however it points to an existing Category. In database there is already Category.Id = 1 with "drama" as CategoryName. Current problem is in the mapping:

```
    CreateMap<BookDto, Book>().AfterMap((s, d) =>
    {
        foreach (var bookCategory in d.BookCategories)
        {
            bookCategory.BookId = s.BookId;
        }
    });
```

[image]

when the above code is about to execute, d.BookCategories is null. So i wonder what's wrong my mapping?

Comment: http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Configuration-validation.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AutoMapper maps automatically members with the same name. Since collections in `Book` and `BookDto` have different names (`BookCategories` vs `Categories`), they have to be mapped explicitly. You can do it in one of the maps and `ReverseMap` will handle the opposite:

```
CreateMap<Book, BookDto>()
    .ForMember(d => d.Categories, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.BookCategories))
    .ReverseMap()
    .AfterMap((s, d) =>
    {
        foreach (var bookCategory in d.BookCategories)
            bookCategory.BookId = s.BookId;
    });
```

But since the join entity contains simply 2 ids, you can avoid the map from `CategoryDto` to `BookCategory` and `AfterMap`, and do the reverse mapping with simple LINQ projection (`Select'):

```
CreateMap<Book, BookDto>()
    .ForMember(d => d.Categories, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.BookCategories))
    .ReverseMap()
    .ForMember(d => d.BookCategories, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.Categories
        .Select(c => new BookCategory { BookId = s.BookId, CategoryId = c.CategoryId })));
```

Comment: have implented this code but getting error..i have asked a qusetion..if possible can u answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63717024/automapper-mapping-with-many-to-may-with-includemembers

Answer (score 0):

In my case (.Net 7) I just need to add the `"requireExactSource": false` property in the vs code launch.json

This is the final launch json:

```
{
        // Use IntelliSense to find out which attributes exist for C# debugging
        // Use hover for the description of the existing attributes
        // For further information visit https://github.com/dotnet/vscode-csharp/blob/main/debugger-launchjson.md
        "name": ".NET Core Launch (web)",
        "type": "coreclr",
        "request": "launch",
        "preLaunchTask": "build",
        // If you have changed target frameworks, make sure to update the program path.
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/Services/AccountOrganizationService/bin/Debug/net7.0/AccountOrganizationService.dll",
        "args": [],
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/Services/AccountOrganizationService",
        "stopAtEntry": true,
        // Enable launching a web browser when ASP.NET Core starts. For more information: https://aka.ms/VSCode-CS-LaunchJson-WebBrowser
        "serverReadyAction": {
            "action": "openExternally",
            "pattern": "\\bNow listening on:\\s+(https?://\\S+)"
        },
        "env": {
            "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
        },
        "sourceFileMap": {
            "/Views": "${workspaceFolder}/Views"
        },
        "requireExactSource": false
    },
```

[image: Debugger error message]