# Automapper with many to many and IncludeMembers

Tags: c#, automapper, fluent

Below is my Class

```
  public class Account
    {
       public int Id { get; set; }
       
       public string AccountNumber { get; set; } = null!;      
       ..other fields
       
       public  SubAccount1 SubAccount1 { get; set; } = null!;
       public  SubAccount2 SubAccount2 { get; set; } = null!;
      public ICollection<AccountCustomer> AccountAndCustomers { get; set; } = new List<AccountCustomer>();   ///Many to many mapping
    }
    
   public class AccountCustomer  
   {
        public int AccountId { get; set; }
        public Account Account { get; set; } = null!;

        public int CustomerId { get; set; }
        public Customer Customer { get; set; } = null!;
        ...other fields
   }
    
 public class SubAccount1
    {
       public int AccountId { get; set; }
       public  Account Account { get; set; } = null!;
       public string  Subfield1 { get; set; } = null!;
        ..other fields
    }
    
    public class SubAccount2
    {
       public int AccountId { get; set; }
       public  Account Account { get; set; } = null!;
       public string  Subfield2 { get; set; } = null!;
        ..other fields
    }
    
 
    public class SubAccount1DTO
    {
    
       public int AccountId { get; set; }   
       
       public string AccountNumber { get; set; } = null!;
  
       public string  Subfield1 { get; set; } = null!;
       
       public IReadOnlyList<CustomerDTO> Customers { get; set; } = new List<CustomerDTO>();
    }
public class CustomerDTO
    {

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string CustomerNo { get; set; } = null!;

        public string FirstName { get; set; } = null!;
         ..other fillds

       }

public class Customer 
    {
      

       public int Id { get; set; }  
       public string? CustomerNo { get; set; } = null!;
       ....other filds
       public ICollection<AccountCustomer> AccountAndCustomers { get; set; } = new List<AccountCustomer>();

}
```

Auto mapper configuration  based on this link  [Automapper many to many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57173907/auto-mapping-with-automapper-from-dto-to-an-entity-with-many-to-many-relations)

```
CreateMap<Customer, CustomerDTO>().ReverseMap();

CreateMap<Account, SubAccount1DTO>()                          
                .IncludeMembers(s => s.SubAccount1)
                .ForMember(d => d.Customers, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.AccountAndCustomers))   ///After include Customers related am getting error
                 .ReverseMap()
                  .AfterMap((s, d) =>
                  {
                      foreach (var accountCustomer in d.AccountAndCustomers)
                          accountCustomer.AccountId = s.AccountId ;
                  });
                             
    CreateMap<SubAccount1, SubAccount1DTO>(MemberList.None)
                  .ForMember(dest => dest.Id, opt => opt.Ignore())
                  .ForMember(dest => dest.AccountNumber, opt => opt.Ignore())
                  .ReverseMap();

 CreateMap<Customer, AccountCustomer>()  ----i dnt no whether this to included
            .ForMember(dest => dest.CustomerId, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Id))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Customer, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.AccountId, opt => opt.Ignore())
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Account, opt => opt.Ignore())
            ;
```

***I need to map Account to SubAccount1DTO and Reversemap. Here SubAccount1DTO has list of customersdto But when i included below line***

*.ForMember(d => d.Customers, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.AccountAndCustomers))*

i am getting below error .. Please suggest

*One or more errors occurred. (The following member on Application.DTOs.Accounts.SubAccount1DTO cannot be mapped:
Customers
Add a custom mapping expression, ignore, add a custom resolver, or modify the destination type Application.DTOs.Accounts.SubAccount1DTO.
Context:
Mapping to member Customers from Domain.Entities.Accounts.Account to Application.DTOs.Accounts.SubAccount1DTO*

Comment: Please include the 2 missing relevant classes - `Customer` and `CustomerDTO`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following mapping

```
.ForMember(d => d.Customers, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.AccountAndCustomers))
```

maps source property of type `ICollection<AccountCustomer>` to destination property of type `IReadOnlyList<CustomerDTO>`.

AutoMapper allows that, but requires you to create map for collection element types - in this specific case, `AccountCustomer` to `CustomerDTO` (in the linked post there is similar mapping from `BookCategory` to  `CategoryDto`).

Hence the minimum you need here is adding something like this to the mapper configuration:

```
CreateMap<AccountCustomer, CustomerDTO>()
    .IncludeMembers(s => s.Customer);
```